# What does a 5V gate drive mean?

Tags: transistors

I need to choose a transistor for my battery supplied application. What does it mean when it says it has a 5V gate drive. Do I need 5V as supply voltage for that transistor? 
What do I have to take care of, when choosing a tansistor?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please supply the part number or a link to the datasheet for specific information

Comment: Actually I am looking for a transistor which can be used for a protection cuircuit of a rechargable battery with 3.7V. Besides the Ron I am not sure about what else I have to take care of when choosing a transistor for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

It means that it can not charge the gate voltage higher than 5V. Therefore you need to find a FET whose parameters (on-resistance or drain current) are acceptable for your application at VGS=5V. I am sure there is some information in the datasheet or in related application notes.

Historically power FETs needed a higher gate drive, but nowadays 5V power FETs are common as well. The main reason behind this reduction is that modern CMOS technologies have a much lower breakdown voltage (nowadays below 1V) where generating 5V output is troublesome if not purely audacious. Even though power chips tend to use higher line width technologies, a high current 5V output is already a challenge to design due to the ringing of the RLC network, which consist of the FET gate (C) and the track and bond wires (L).

Comment: So the 5V is just an upper limit. As my cuircuit will be supplied by an USB cable 5V will be the maximum anyway. So do I need a transistor with this limit or a lower / higher one?

Comment: The transistor has to provide the performance parameter what your design requires at VGS=5V. It is usually drain-source resistance or drain current. It will not hurt you if your transistor can withstand 15V gate-source voltage or 120V drain-source voltage. Note: you might need a bypass cap right next to the driver's supply pin with a stored charges at 5V many times higher than the gate charge of your switching device, otherwise the supply will drop due to the high current transient, and the transistor will not be loaded to the desired 5V as fast.